# PHP Composer install

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I'm in a console with a ssh connection to a server.
Now I have a clone of my project from git.

If I do the following thing: `php composer.phar install` I get the next error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle dev-master.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle dev-master requires jdorn/sql-formatter >=1.1,<2.0 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.0.x-dev.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.0.x-dev requires jdorn/sql-formatter >=1.1,<2.0 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-i18n 2.0.5 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-i18n 2.0.5.
    - zendframework/zend-i18n 2.0.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 4
    - zendframework/zend-i18n 2.0.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - zendframework/zend-validator 2.0.5 requires zendframework/zend-i18n 2.0.5 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-i18n 2.0.5.
    - Installation request for zendframework/zend-validator 2.0.5 -> satisfiable by zendframework/zend-validator 2.0.5.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

My composer.js:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "mv/name1-bundle" : "*",
        "mv/name2-bundle" : "*",
        "psliwa/pdf-bundle": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:name1/name1bundle.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:name2/name2bundle.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
        },
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "http://packagist.org/"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "public_html",
        "symfony-assets-install": "symlink"
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, local it works like a charm! but on the server it gives me errors. What is the problem and how to solve this?

Oh and I can't do `php composer.phar update` (extern hosted server)

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies                                 

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in phar:///composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 47
```

Thnx.

Comment: Should be `composer.json`, not `composer.js`.

Comment: its probably a typo.. from a year ago.. and if it was my real file name I couldn't do `composer update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget` the newest composer.phar to make sure you're on the safe side there. Or even better you can do:

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

Problems 1 and 2 most likely have some illegal notation for versions. Try adding the `jdorn/sql-formatter` package directly to your own requirements with a specific version number.

Problems 3 and 4 have nothing to do with composer. The PHP extension `intl` is not installed on your system but it's a required dependency of some ZF2 components. Which means you need to install it or compile it into PHP on your server.

Comment: What strange is about the ```intl``` extension is that local it works fine, and I diddn't install that extension. I even don't use that extension. Is there a way to ignore this message to continue?

Comment: I assume you're using some kind of AMP bundle locally, like Zend Server CE or something. Then that extension would already be bundled with it. And no, you can't ignore it, Zend-i18n uses this extension, that's why it's a dependency. If you don't need zend-i18n, then don't install it.

Comment: What I'm tying to say is, I had the vendors pasted manually by FTP to the server. Everything works like a charm! So that means I don't use that extension. But I need zend for my PDF bundle: https://github.com/psliwa/PdfBundle

Comment: Your composer.json doesn't mention any Zend Framework components, why is that if you need them? Your PDF bundle should require the ZF components this bundle needs (and not the whole framework).

Comment: The bundle does not extend all Zend Frameworks componetents. I found in the i18n component a requirement of the intl extenstion :( I have 2 options, 1: build a own PDF library 2: search a other one

Comment: No, it's the other way around, intl is a dependency of i18n, that means, zend-i18n NEEDS the PHP intl extension. That does NOT mean you need to use the whole ZF. Just install intl and you're fine.

Comment: I often wonder why zero score accepted answers even exist?! ;)